# ¿Existen genéricos para datos primitivos en Java?

Tags: java, variables, conversión-de-tipos, genericos

Esta es una pregunta un tanto extraña, así que la expresare con un ejemplo:

Digamos que tengo un método `int operación(int a, int b)`. El código de las operaciones internas que hace no cambiarían en lo absoluto si utilizara float, long o double en lugar de int (digamos que son puras sumas). Yo quiero que ese mismo método sirva para cualquier tipo de dato primitivo numérico, sin tener que reescribirlo varias veces.

Podría simplemente crear un método base usando double y hacer que todos los métodos usen ese mismo, y solo convertir los tipos de datos:

```
double operacion(double a, double b){...}

int operacion(int a, int b) {
 return (int)(operacion((double)(a),(double)(b)))
}
```

Pero eso podría ocupar procesamiento y RAM de más (si, despreciable, pero ahí esta). Si uso `int operacion(int a, int b)`, aunque este sea un tipo de dato mas compacto, igual habrá cálculos con double, porque `int operacion(int a, int b)` usa `double operacion(double a, double b)`. Tal vez el procesamiento requerido sea exactamente el mismo (no se muy bien como funciona eso) pero definitivamente un método ocuparía mas memoria que el otro. Lo que quiero es evitar que se use memoria y procesamiento de más, sin tener que escribir tanto (porque la clase que estoy haciendo contiene muchos métodos así).

Mi pregunta es si existe alguna herramienta para poder hacer esto de manera optima. Por ejemplo, una especie de variable comodín para el tipo de dato, o algo como usar un Object o Class pero en datos primitivos, tal vez algo como un genérico de datos primitivos. Se que suena extraño y dudo que algo así exista, pero no seria la primera vez que Java me sorprende con una funcionalidad fuera de lo común. Y si no existe nada por el estilo, me gustaría saber si hay algún lenguaje con una funcionalidad así.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si funcionan los genéricos, aunque no se puede con datos primitivos por que los parámetros genéricos siempre reciben argumentos de objetos pero siempre se puede utilizar un `wrapper` para que funcione perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

Los genéricos por muy sorprendente que te parezca **¡no funcionan con datos primitivos!**

Todo lo que uses en un genérico debe de ser un objeto, es decir, tu no puedes tener un

```
List<int> ints = new ArrayList<int>();
```

> estas bien mek*<sup>1</sup>

Para evitarse el tedioso problema de la conversión se inventaron el *auto-unboxing*  y el *autoboxing*, a ambos en conjunto se les conoce como *boxing*<sup>2</sup>.

La ventaja es que si pones tu genérico a un tipo que no sea primitivo, hará el proceso de boxing para tí.

Antes de los genéricos simplemente usabas `Object`, **que es la solución que iqanasoft te sugiere**.

Lo nuevo y lo de moda es **usar Streams** desde Java 8.

Allí hay algunos tipos de stream convenientemente de primitivos como es el caso de `IntStream` y que dependiendo que tan bueno sea tu compilador puede automáticamente crearte un `IntStream` si lo creas de puros `int` an vez de un simple y mortal `Stream<Integer>`, es por ello que a veces verás c+odigo tan feo como

```
Stream<Client> intStream = (Stream<Client>) (Stream<?>)stream
```

Que agarra tu streanm de tipo Object y trata de convertirlo.

O menos feo...

```
Stream.of(objects)
    .filter(c -> c instanceof Client)
    .map(c -> (Client) c)
```

Así que para resolver tu problema tendrías cosas como:

```
int sum = Arrays.asList(33,45)
  .stream()
  .mapToInt(i -> i)
  .sum();
```

Para ello te recomiendo leer todos los métodos de la clase `Stream` y encadenar métodos, aprovechando que gracias al uso interno que hace de `Optional`, si algo no se cumple no hace más cálculos de lo necesario.

```
Arrays.asList(33,45).stream()
    .filter(Integer.class::isInstance)
    .map (Integer.class::cast)
```

Uno por cada tipo de dato que sepas como sumar y al final sumar el resultado de los streams por cada tipo.

## Epílogo

Y como para que te foguees un poco más en eso, te dejo tres ejercicios en codewars<sup>3</sup> de mi autoría en orden de dificultad creciente:

1. [Printing Array elements with Comma delimiters](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56e2f59fb2ed128081001328)
2. [Printing Array elements with Comma delimiters II](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5711d95f159cde99e0000249)
3. [Printing Array elements with Comma delimiters III](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58def784f42231a95e00012f)

## Notas al pié

<sup>1</sup> Osea no sale así, pero debería salir así el error xD

<sup>2</sup> así te evitas ese tipo de declaraciones horribles y verbosas, tu sabes... como cuando creas un arreglo de shorts de manera inline

<sup>3</sup> Si no te has registrado, este es mi link de referidos [www.codewars.com/r/vf5AJA](https://www.codewars.com/r/vf5AJA), te permitirá registrarte y agregarme la mismo tiempo en dicha plataforma.

Answer (score 0):

Siendo honestos en java no existe esa funcionalidad que estas solicitando, mi recomendacion es usar la sobrecarga de metodos

```
public double operation(double a, double b)
public long operation(long a, long b)
public int operation(int a, int b)
public float operation(float a, float b)
```

Una alternativa rebuscada es que uses los generics de java y la clase [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) para  crear un metodo que soporte "cualquier tipo" de dato que extienda de la clase [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)( int, double, float) y dentro del metodo atraves de if/else valides el tipo de dato correcto y puedas proceder al casting mas correcto.

Pero siendo honestos esta solucion deja mucho que desear y el codigo es poco mantenible en mi opinion.